# Text is not being entered in the box that has focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a few instances of a user control that has just a TextBox to search for items.

Now I see a very funny thing.  The cursor is in one uc TextBox but the text I type appears in another uc TextBox.

How can this be possible.

And how can I fix it?!

**Edit: Added image:**

[image: Notice the cursor in model number, but the txt is in upc]

Notice the cursor in model number, but the text is in upc.

**Edit: Added Code:**

```
Private Sub TxtScan_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TxtScan.KeyDown
  'When typing in the model number uc I see that the sender
  'is the txtbox is the one in the UPC user control.
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need to post some code... is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Post code, example screen shots.  Seems like your getter / setter properties are not defined correctly.

Comment: Is there any kind of binding? It almost looks like the text box you're typing in is bound to a property OneWayToSource and the property is bound to the other text box OneWay. I think the text should still show up and it looks like there are characters being typed as the cursor isn't at the beginning any longer. Is that textbox's font color white, by chance?

Comment: No to all... one thing I noticed that after I place focus to upc and back to model it starts working normal.

Comment: That's odd. Did you trace everything in code - is it possible the focus is going back and forth and you're not noticing it? As you're typing, that is.

Comment: Is that code in the UC or the form containing both of UC's?

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: I can't figure out which code produced the problem. it looks like a .net bug. Since my code does nothing and this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got the code doing that stupid thing.. I still believe its a .net bug. it should of take over the focus when I enter the textbox.

```
    Private Sub CustomerNo_Validated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CustomerNo.Validated
    SearchItem_UPC.TxtScan.Focus()
    End Sub
```

When I took out this line it works normal.

Comment: It's not a bug.  You told it to focus somewhere else and it did.

Comment: The blinking line in any textbox is a carat.  The mouse pointer you move around the screen is a cursor.